# Excel is not able to access from C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

This is regarding Excel issue we are facing in Production. We have a asp.net application which is reading an Excel from shared drive. We are having issues with Dcom configuration and security settings on our server which is preventing to complete the process.

We currently running the process from service account which is defined in Dcom Identity tab.

We have full permission to the shared drive for the service account from where the application is reading the file. But still we are getting the error as below. (Error Message : Microsoft cannot access the file: There are several possible reasons: The file name or path does not exist, The file is being used by another program, The workbook you are trying to save has the same name as a currently open workbook )

We also have full permission for service account on the excel location . As the application will be run by different users we cannot change the DCom setting to ‘Interactive User’. Business wants the application to be run using on service account. 
If we change it to ‘Interactive user’ it is working as expected and Excel is opening without any issue.

Service account is also added to COM Property settings.

I created Desktop folder under Windows\System32\Config\systemprofile\desktop and Windows\SysWow64\Config\systemprofile\desktop and gave full permissions with service account, but issue did not resolve the issue.

Could you please help us.

Comment: Excel + COM Automation + ASP.Net is very strongly advised against, Its simply not designed to work in that environment. If you just need to read the file there are other libraries/odbc approaches.

Comment: Looking for some help on this issue?  Appreciated your suggestion

Comment: Use open XML SDK.      https://forums.asp.net/t/1908949.aspx?Asp+net+COM+Exception+Excel+Interoperability

Answer (score -1):

```
string con =
  @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=D:\temp\test.xls;" + 
  @"Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;'";    
using(OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(con))
{
    connection.Open();
    OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("select * from [Sheet1$]", connection); 
    using(OleDbDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
         while(dr.Read())
         {
             var row1Col0 = dr[0];
             Console.WriteLine(row1Col0);
         }
    }
}
```

try this . guess this will work for you fine

Comment: Hi Tehseen, thanks for your reply I tried the above code still I'm getting the same error. it is throwing the error on below line of code. excel.Workbooks.Open("path",oMissing,....);

Comment: Can anybody help on this issue? {System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x800A03EC): Microsoft Excel cannot access the file '\\appcomp1\TEST\Final.xls'. There are several possible reasons:• The file name or path does not exist.
• The file is being used by another program.
• The workbook you are trying to save has the same name as a currently open workbook.